# Creating adjacency matrix from multiple clustering results of various sizes

Tags: python, networkx

I have collected outputs from several clustering algorithms on the same data set, based on which I would like to generate an adjacency matrix indicating in how many different runs any two samples were clustered together. I.e. for each `I = 10` clusterings, I have a one-hot representation `N x C_i` indicating whether or not the sample `n` belongs to cluster `c` (for the i'th run), with the possibility of different (amount of) clusters for each run. The goal is then to build an adjacency matrix `N x N` on which I can threshold and select only consistent clusters for further analysis.

It is quite easy to build an algorithm that does this:

```
n_samples = runs[0].shape[0]
i = []
j = []

for iter_no, ca in enumerate(runs):
    print("Processing adjacency", iter_no)
    for col in range(ca.shape[1]):
        comb = itertools.combinations(np.where(ca[:, col])[0], 2)
        for c in comb:
            i.append(c[0])
            j.append(c[1])

i = np.array(i)
j = np.array(j)
adj_mat = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(len(i)), (i, j)), shape=[n_samples, n_samples])
```

This scales *very poorly* with cluster size, and I typically have `N = 15000` with cluster sizes occasionally reaching 12k. Hence, I'm looking for the `networkx` library to possibly speed this up? Is there any obvious way to do this?

**UPDATE: Solution found (see answer).**

Answer (score 1):

**Linear algebra to the rescue:**

```
assert len(runs) > 0
N = runs[0].shape[0]
R = len(runs)

# Iteratively populate the output matrix (dense)
S = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.int8)
for i, scan in enumerate(runs):
    print("Adjacency", i)
    S += np.matmul(scan, scan.T).astype(np.int8)

# Convert to sparse and return
return scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(S)
```